# Exam package: use \footnote inside \uplevel

Tags: footnotes, exam

In the latex exam package, there is an `\uplevel{}` option for making instruction among questions.  However, the `\footnote` command does not work. The number appears but, the text is not.

```
\uplevel{Please read the instructions mentioned before\footnote{The Turing machine lecture.} first.}
```

More interestingly, I see a number gap in the output among footnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [examdoc:Page 49](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf) specified, one must use  `EnvUplevel` environment instead `\uplevel` and `EnvFullwidth` rather `\fullwidth` to be enabled to use verbatim materials.
So this will solve the problem!

Hence the mentioned code should be:

```
\begin{EnvUplevel} 
    Please read the instructions mentioned before\footnote{The Turing machine lecture.} first. 
\end{EnvUplevel}
```